# Application Gateway Configuration - passthrough to server

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-application-gateway

My application gateway/WAF is setup end to end ssl, does any one know if it can just passthrough requests to like an app server for a desktop client if the Public FQDN is resolving to the app gateway or would i need another device for this?

if this is possible how would i go about doing it with Azure's App GW / WAF?

if not any reccomenations on Virt Applicances.

Comment: Since you used Applicaiton gateway, all triffic from outside will go through the gateway. It's not possible to the server via Applicaiton gateway configuration .

Answer (score 0):

Application Gateway now supports re-encrypt SSL traffic but passthrough is not supported.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-backend-ssl